# Why Ajax Function is not responding on button click event

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=09e7a4e8ee418a607b4fcec06929900e",
    async: true,
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#weather").text(Math.floor(data.main.temp - 273.15) + decodeURI('%C2%B0') + "C") ///Add the weather from api
      $("#location").text(data.name);
      $('#Status').text(data.weather[0].main)
      if (data.weather[0].icon == "10n") {
        var imgurl = "/Images/showerrain.jpg"
        $('#Weather-Header').css('background-image', 'url(https://media.giphy.com/media/t7Qb8655Z1VfBGr5XB/giphy.gif)', 'background-size', 'cover', 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
      }
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(ex) {

      console.log("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

When I Call ajax via document.ready it works fine, when I call the same ajax in button click event it does not respond even with the error, Kindly help, Find below my button click event code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Searchbut").click('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chennai&APPID=09e7a4e8ee418a607b4fcec06929900e",
      async: true,
      type: "GET",
      datatype: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#weather").text(Math.floor(data.main.temp - 273.15) + decodeURI('%C2%B0') + "C") ///Add the weather from api
        $("#location").text(data.name);
        $('#Status').text(data.weather[0].main)
        if (data.weather[0].icon == "10n") {
          var imgurl = "/Images/showerrain.jpg"
          $('#Weather-Header').css('background-image', 'url(https://media.giphy.com/media/t7Qb8655Z1VfBGr5XB/giphy.gif)', 'background-size', 'cover', 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
        }
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function(ex) {

        console.log("Error");
      }

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `$("#Searchbut").click('click', ... );` is not correct. The first argument is invalid. Either use `.on('click', function() { ... })` or just `.click(function() { ... })`.

Comment: Here is the documentation link for Tyler's Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Even I use the above method, It enter into the condition but Ajax part is not working

Comment: You can do it `$(document).on('click','#Searchbut', function ()` and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passed to the click function is incorrect. The click() method triggers the click event, or attaches a function to run when a click event occurs.

**SYNTAX**

Trigger the click event for the selected elements:

```
$(selector).click()
```

Attach a function to the click event:

```
$(selector).click(function)
```

You can as well use the **on() method**. The on() method attaches one or more event handlers for the selected elements and child elements.

Therefore, you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $("#Searchbut").on('click', function () {

          $.ajax({
              url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chennai&APPID=09e7a4e8ee418a607b4fcec06929900e",
              async: true,
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  $("#weather").text(Math.floor(data.main.temp - 273.15) + decodeURI('%C2%B0') + "C")///Add the weather from api
                  $("#location").text(data.name);
                  $('#Status').text(data.weather[0].main)
                  if (data.weather[0].icon == "10n") {
                      var imgurl = "/Images/showerrain.jpg"
                      $('#Weather-Header').css('background-image', 'url(https://media.giphy.com/media/t7Qb8655Z1VfBGr5XB/giphy.gif)', 'background-size', 'cover', 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
                  }
                  alert(data);
              },
              error: function (ex) {

                  console.log("Error");
              }

          });
      });
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $("#Searchbut").click(function () {

          $.ajax({
              url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chennai&APPID=09e7a4e8ee418a607b4fcec06929900e",
              async: true,
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  $("#weather").text(Math.floor(data.main.temp - 273.15) + decodeURI('%C2%B0') + "C")///Add the weather from api
                  $("#location").text(data.name);
                  $('#Status').text(data.weather[0].main)
                  if (data.weather[0].icon == "10n") {
                      var imgurl = "/Images/showerrain.jpg"
                      $('#Weather-Header').css('background-image', 'url(https://media.giphy.com/media/t7Qb8655Z1VfBGr5XB/giphy.gif)', 'background-size', 'cover', 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
                  }
                  alert(data);
              },
              error: function (ex) {

                  console.log("Error");
              }

          });
      });
```

Comment: Anyway I have used your as    $("#Searchbut").click(function () { alert('Hello') --ajax part-- }, alert part is working but ajax is not working @lewa bammy stephen

Comment: It is `dataType` not `datatype`.